# Animation issue when becomefirstresponder

Tags: swift3, uisearchbar, uiviewanimation

I'm having a problem, I do not know if it's a strange or expected behavior.

The context is:

I have a UISearchView embedded on my navigationBar, everything works like a charm. The problem is that I need to set the focus on the searchBar automatically.

I'm calling becomeFirstResponder, it works, but I have two scenarios.

1.- Call it before viewDidAppear: When called before loading items, the transitions show a blank view and suddenly all items appear, with the searchBar focused and the keyboard on the screen. Obviously I do not want the white view.
This covers viewWillLoad, viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear

2.- Calling the viewDidAppear: The blank view is gone, but the focus occurs without animation, the cursor in the searchBar jumps to the left, the placeholder text jumps to the left and the keyboard appears (maybe, not sure, there is 0.1 seconds of animation) and it looks odd.

I have tried with an asynchronous dispatch of the becomeFirstResponder, but all the screens flash for a moment and it not solve the problem.

Is like the animation is ocurring "in the background"

Does anybody have an idea?